# Calculating an antipodal point on a sphere

Tags: geometry

Consider a 3-sphere at the origin $(0,0,0)$.  Let $s_1 = (x,y,z)$ be a point somewhere on the surface of the sphere.  How do I calculate the antipodal point $s_1^* = (x^*,y^*,z^*)$?

Comment: How are you defining an antipodal point? That will give you some ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a sphere centered at the origin, the antipodal point is the one you obtain by negating all coordinates: $s_1^*=(-x,-y,-z)$.

Note that “3-sphere” usually refers to an object in fourdimensional space. So I think you mean 2-sphere. See also [$n$-sphere at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere).